# Bash Script: Comparing two text files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text

I am wondering how I can do this efficiently.
Given two files, say a.txt and b.txt, I want to write a bash script to do the following:

Every line in a.txt containing '*' that does not exist in b.txt will be added at the end of b.txt with a time stamp.

I can do the first and last parts by

`grep "*" a.txt
echo "$(date)" >> b.txt`

but I don't know how about the rest.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some examples of your files and the expected output.

Comment: There is no way of being remotely efficient in bash. Does this _need_ to be bash? I see you are at least open to non-bash tools like `grep`, so can we also use `awk` or `sed` or `perl` etc? The shell, any shell, is a horrible tool for text processing: it will always be slow and inefficient.

Comment: @terdon thank your for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a third file for results so you don't mess the b.txt file.
You could try this:

```
cp b.txt c.txt 
for line in $(grep '*' a.txt); do
    # for each line found in a.txt
    echo "Found: $line"
    grep -q $line b.txt   # check its presence in b.txt
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        # if the result of the grep is not equal to 0
        # it means that the line has not been found in b.txt
        # then print the line in a third file with the leading timestamp
        echo "$(date): $line" >> c.txt
    fi
done
```

It's clear that maybe you should just improve the grep since I don't know hoe the row where you are searching the '*' is composed.